# play html5 video inside iframe from play button in parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, video

I have a web page which contains a video in an iframe.  The videos in the iframe can be changed by pressing links on the page.
I have a play and pause button on the parent page that I want to use to start and stop playback of the videos in the iframe.

on a page without an iframe i used this code to make the video play and pause

```
    <script> 
var vid = document.getElementById("VIDEO"); 

function playVid() { 
    VIDEO.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
    VIDEO.pause(); 
} 
</script>
```

I need to get this script to reference the video in the iframe.  Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Note: the videos appearing in the iframes are each embedded on their own page so I could set them to not show play controls and to play looped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iframe document should be on the same domain as the original one, instead you'll fall under the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restriction.

If it's ok, then here is an example:

**index.html**

```
<iframe src="frame.html" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;" id="video_frame"></iframe>
<br/><button type="button" onclick="play_video()">Play</button>
<script>
function play_video()
{
    document.getElementById('video_frame').contentWindow.playVid();
}
</script>
```

**frame.html**

```
<embed id="VIDEO" ... />
<script> 
var vid = document.getElementById("VIDEO"); 

function playVid() { 
    VIDEO.play(); 
} 

function pauseVid() { 
    VIDEO.pause(); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly.  You have no idea how many different ways I tried to do that.  My big mistake was trying to put all of the script in the parent. Give yourself a pat on the back ;)

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: VIDEO.play is not a function** I'm getting this error while running